# Riemann and Lebesgue integral on Manifolds

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, lebesgue-measure

Our Mathematical analysis lecturer said the course (2 year BS MATH) will be more Lebesgue measurement and integration focused, rather that the traditional  Riemann one. She said, even thought it is more difficult to understand, it finds more applications in different fields, like statistics...

We are studying **manifolds** from a Lebesgue M&I perspective. Most of the literature I know in  Russian, explains manifolds from the Riemann integral perspective.

**Could you recomend me literature in English or Russian explaining manifolds from a Lebesgue perspective?**

PS.I understand this post might not belong to this community. If you know a website fitting my request let me know in the comments.

Comment: Correct spelling:  *Riemann* and *Lebesgue*

Comment: Manifolds are locally compact Hausdorff spaces, the theory of integration that leads to Riesz representation is enough. Forms and volume elements and all that Jazz provide linear operators that can then be extended to Radon-measures. See See for example Rudin's RCA (section on Riesz representation) or any other good book on Measure theory and Integration for that result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an introduction to manifolds that uses the Lebesgue integral there is Vector Analysis by Janich (a great book in any case). But really, unless the course is analysis focused ($L^2$ space of functions on the manifold, differential operators, convergence of sequences of functions etc...), it shouldn't matter that much what kind of integral you use